# Sourcing different config files

Tags: python, configparser

I need to read a certain path from three different possible places in two config files:

- A global one, `/etc/program.conf`
- A local one, `~/.config/program/config`

The local one has a `[DEFAULT]` section and may or may not have a per case specific section, say `[case]`. I'd like to

1. Read the path given by the case-specific section of the local config
2. Absent that, read the path given by the default section of the local config
3. Absent that, read the path given by the global config
4. Absent that (!), provide a default path

I'm using `configparser` in Python. This is actually not a difficult problem, but the solution I've come up with strikes me as inelegant and clunky. As this is, I think, a fairly common situation, I thought I'd ask more experienced programmers for better solutions.

The code I have is this:

```
def retrieve_download_path(feed):
    download_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    if os.path.isfile(CONFIG_FILENAME_GLOBAL):
        config.read(CONFIG_FILENAME_GLOBAL)
        if config.has_option('DEFAULT','Download directory'):
            download_path = os.path.expanduser(config['DEFAULT']['Download directory'])
    if os.path.isfile(CONFIG_FILENAME_USER):
        config.read(CONFIG_FILENAME_USER)
        if config.has_option(feed,'Download directory'):
            download_path = os.path.expanduser(config[feed]['Download directory'])
        elif config.has_option('DEFAULT','Download directory'):
            download_path = os.path.expanduser(config['DEFAULT']['Download directory'])
    return download_path
```

How may I improve this? What's the usual way of sourcing different config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`configparser`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) seems to provide support for what you're trying to implement, specifically multiple config files and a `DEFAULT` section.

Does this do what you want?

```
def retrieve_download_path(feed):
    # Read the config files.
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read((CONFIG_FILENAME_GLOBAL, CONFIG_FILENAME_USER))

    # Resolve the section (configparser doesn't fallback to DEFAULT if the entire section is missing).
    section = feed if config.has_section(feed) else config.default_section

    # Extract the download path.
    download_path = config.get(section, 'Download directory', fallback='~/Downloads')

    # Expand the user directory.
    return os.path.expanduser(download_path)
```

The only difference I see is that will allow (and consult) a `DEFAULT` section in the global config file (which seems desirable).

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I had overlooked the possibility of reading different files. Is there a way to establish a hierarchy among them, though? I mean: the local file should take preeminence, the global as a default, etc.

Comment: @Schiphol I'm pretty sure that the order of the filenames passed to [`read()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) determines the precedence. I think `read()` expects them in reverse-precedence order, which seems backwards to me, but whatever. So the file you want consulted first should be the last filename passed to `read()`. (And if I'm wrong, reverse the list. :) And the "fallback" (parameter to [`get()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.get)) is always returned as a last resort.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work: suppose feed is "blah"; if neither CONFIG_FILENAME_GLOBAL nor _USER have a ["blah"] section, config.get goes directly to the fallback, without checking the ["DEFAULT"] section.

Comment: @Schiphol You are correct. I was surprised that configparser only handles missing _options_, not missing _sections_. I added a line to fallback to the default section if the section is missing. This worked in my limited testing.

Comment: This looks indeed the best one can do. Thanks again for all the help!